# Sending mail through proxy server in C#

Tags: c#, email, proxy, smtp

I have implemented a desktop application.I need to send mail.My application can send mail directly.Now i need to implement this tasks when PC is connected through a proxy server.If any one has done it before please help me..

Comment: Maybe this can help, [HOW TO: Send Mail with Proxy Server That Is Configured Manually by Using Collaboration Data Objects for Windows in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310233)

Comment: What kind of proxy are you sitting behind? Are you sure it supports smtp?

Comment: May be answer you are looking is available at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446001/send-smtp-mail-from-gmail-live-aol-or-yahoo-accounts-when-my-pc-is-connected-v/42719817#42719817

Answer (score 0):

Mail uses smpt. I assume your goal is connecting through an isp/company provided proxy. Those usually only handles http/https. You will not be able to use such a proxy for sending mails since they use different protocols.

Maybe your isp/company have an upstream smtp you can use?

Comment: WHUT? I doubt that a [proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) can act solely as an _HTTP_ proxy. In my opinion, a proxy server can handle _any_ procotol it was designed for.

Comment: PC is connected through a proxy server. Seems to indicate it is a proxy server. I for one have never seen a proxy server able to handle anything other than http(except socks proxy)

Comment: Yeah sure, but I don't think that is what op is sitting behind.

Comment: Hehe, and I don't think that he was _not_ having an SMTP proxy. Your turn ;-)